# Discuss the convergence of the following integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have to discuss the convergence of the following improper integrals:

$$ a) \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(x-x^2)^\frac{1}{2} }\,dx $$
$$ b) \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{1-x^3}\,dx $$
$$ c) \int_{0}^1 \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx $$

I am trying to use the comparison test (Note that I have to discuss the convergence without evaluating the integrals themselves), but I haven't found nice integrals to compare to yet. Any ideas, hints, or suggestions?

Comment: General hint is - consider neighbourhood of critical point(s) and use equivalence functions.

Comment: Warning: Just because there is a vertical asymptote, does not mean divergent. But the anti derivatives can be calculated, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

a)

Let $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}$$

Near $ 0$ ,
$$f(x)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
near $ 1$,

$$f(x)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$

Both integrales $\int_0f $ and $ \int^1f $ converge, so $ \int_0^1f $ is convergent.

b)

Let $$ g(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}$$
Near $ 1$,
$$g(x)\sim \frac{1}{3(1-x)}$$
thus
$$\int_0^1g \text{ diverges}$$

c)

With the substitution $ t=\sqrt{x} $,
the integrale becomes

$$4\int_0^1\ln(t)dt $$
which is known to be convergent.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate a little bit on your "near x point"- argument? Why does that work, from a rigorous point of view? I don't quite see why

Comment: @DougL  This is the limit comparison test .