# A question about convergence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

In this post
[Discuss the convergence of the following integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146035/discuss-the-convergence-of-the-following-integrals/4146048#4146048) I asked about the convergence of a few integrals integrals, among them was this one:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(x-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}} $$

Now, in one of the answers I was told to note that if $f(x)= \frac{1}{(x-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}}$, then $f$ $\sim$ $\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{2}}$ near $0$ and $f$ $\sim$  $\frac{1}{(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}}$ near 1. And so the convergence of $f$ near those points follows from the convergence of the other functions. Can you please show (as rigorously as possible) why this is a valid argument ?

Note. I think this has to do with the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I took part in comments in your linked question, then, feeling certain responsibility, let me bring little sketch of proof for following theorem: Suppose we have non negative functions $f, g$ and exists  $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=K\gt 0$, then both improper integrals $\int\limits_{a}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and  $\int\limits_{a}^{+\infty}g(x)\,dx$ exists simultaneously.

For proof is enough to write, from definition of limit, inequality $K-\varepsilon \lt \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\lt K+\varepsilon $ and then use comparison test, which you know, as wrote in mentioned post.

Now, hope, it's easy to use this way also for improper integral in finite point.